# How can I get the binary representation of a value

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decimal to binary conversion in c #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954962/decimal-to-binary-conversion-in-c)

I have number such as 3, 432, 1, etc . Where I need to convert these number to set of zero & ones, and then store these bits in an array of integers, but not sure how I can get the bits representation of any integer.

Comment: Please put "c# integer to binary" to google. And the first link will be (surprise-surprise) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954962/decimal-to-binary-conversion-in-c PS: always consult to google before trying to do that with humans - don't think your issue is unique.

Comment: ...which is not quite what he's asing

Comment: `"but not sure how I can get the bits representation of any integer."` which is answered in the duplicate.

Comment: @Rawling: using the same magic tool (the google) you can change the question to "c# integer to array of bytes" and get (surprise-surprise) another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318933/c-sharp-int-to-byte But indeed, for some people using such a difficult tool like google is a rocket science

Comment: There we go, then :p Edit: no wait, that's a byte per byte, not an int per bit.

Comment: @zerkms Bits aren't bytes though :P

Comment: @phant0m: agree. But I won't put the 3rd google query here (it's not even funny anymore). But there is an answer for bits there as well.

Comment: @zerkms Now who'd have thought you could find [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758196/convert-int-to-a-bit-array-in-net) on Google.

Answer (score 19):

Use [Convert.ToString Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx)

> Converts the value of a 32-bit signed integer to its equivalent string
>   representation in a specified base.

```
int val = 10;
string binaryNumberString = Convert.ToString(val, 2);
```

To put them in an int array try:

```
int[] arr = new int[binaryNumberString.Length];
int i=0;
foreach (var ch in binaryNumberString)
{
    arr[i++] = Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Well, it wasn't right, but now it is! +1

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Convert.ToString()` method

```
int n = 50;
int b = 2;

string binaryForm = Convert.ToString(n, b);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but what does base means in this case?

Comment: @Vinod base is a keyword in c#

Comment: ya i know but how it will affect the returned bit values i mean , say i define the base as 2 what will be different if i define the base as 8

Comment: @Nick, My bad. Yes, the variable should be renamed to a non-keyword.

`int reqBase = 2;`