# Get an array of bits that represent an int in c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit

Is there a way to show the representation of an int in bits in c#?

i.e.

```
1  = 00001
20 = 10100
```

etc.

I have tried using BitConverter with no luck. This should be simple, but I can't find a solution!

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758196/convert-int-to-a-bit-array-in-net seems to have a few solutions to your question.

Comment: Thanks @EdgySwingsetAcid - knew this had to be on SO somewhere, just couldn't find it! Cue the votes to close...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [Convert.ToString(value, base)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx)

Converts the value of a 32-bit signed integer to its equivalent string representation in a specified base.  Specify 2 for the base.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner using linq:

```
var myint = 20;
var bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(b => (myint >> b) & 1);
// { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ... }
```

Of course this is in reverse order, to swap it around just use:

```
var myint = 20;
var bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(b => (myint >> (31 - b)) & 1);
// { ..., 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 }
```

Comment: That's smart! Thank you. I will accept the Convert.ToString() answer since it seems to be a more standard method. But I like this answer a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at using a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

```
var array = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(1));
```