# VB.Net serial communication return wrong reading after time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, fpga

I have faced this problem for two weeks and still cannot fix it. I press "Read" button to send a command through VB.Net to ATmega to communicate with FPGA and then read registers back. At first, everything looks fine, but after I keep pressing "Read" button for several times(randomly), this error occurs. It returns wrong value(ASCII) with same pattern and the pattern is similar with the correct reading. And after the error occurs, the reading keeps returning this wrong pattern and cannot return correct reading back unless I unplug my serial device and plugin again. I am using Visual Basic 2010 with .Net4.0 . I have tried to use ReadChr/Readbyte functions but the error still occur. Also I tried to communicate with my device using Arduino serial monitor to send code directly and receive reading back. Error didn't occur in about 100+ trials but I can't sure it won't occur or just haven't occured.

Here is the some code of the "Read" button:

```
Private Sub btnRead_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click
        btnRead.Enabled = False
        btnSend.Enabled = False
        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim Check1 As String
        Dim temp As Integer
        Dim buffer(16) As Byte
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (dgvRegMap.RowCount - 1)
            dgvRegMap.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
        Loop
        dgvRegMap.Refresh()
        AxMSComm1.DiscardNull = False
        AxMSComm1.BaudRate = 115200
        AxMSComm1.Open()
        For j = 0 To 15
            dgvRegMap.Rows.Add()
            strTemp = "1" & FnDec2Bin(j, 4) & TextBox3.Text & "000000000000000000000000"
            Check1 = ""
            AxMSComm1.Write(strTemp)
            AxMSComm1.DiscardOutBuffer()
            Thread.Sleep(10)
            temp = AxMSComm1.BytesToRead
            Convert.ToByte(AxMSComm1.Read(buffer, 0, temp))
            Dim s As String = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(buffer)
            Check1 = s
            For i = 0 To 15
                dgvRegMap.Rows(j).Cells("Bit" & CStr(i)).Value = CStr(Mid(Check1, i + 1, 1))
            Next
            dgvRegMap.Rows(j).Cells("Address").Value = j
            dgvRegMap.Refresh()
            AxMSComm1.DiscardInBuffer()
            Thread.Sleep(10)
        Next j
        AxMSComm1.Close()
        Thread.Sleep(50)
        btnRead.Enabled = True
        btnSend.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

Correct Reading:
[image]

Wrong Reading:
[image]

Comment: `DiscardOutBuffer()` is called immediately after `Write()`. `DiscardOutBuffer()` just discards the data, not the `Flush()`(promotes output). Even though it is binary data, `Encoding...GetString()` is called after `Read()` to convert it to a character string. It is considered that the usage is not suitable for the function or data attribute. If you want to convert to bit units, refer to this article. [Convert int to a bit array in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6758196/9014308), [Get an array of bits that represent an int in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18221769/9014308)

Comment: Thanks for the help. But even if I tried to read data using ReadChar/Readbyte/the method you suggest, the problem still exist. I can receive correct data for some times, but the error still occur soon.