# Initialize BitArray from integer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to initialize a System.BitArray instance from integer value. However, it looks like I don't get the right values.

My code is

```
        var b = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(0xfa2));
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Count; i++)
        {
            char c = b[i] ? '1' : '0';
            Console.Write(c);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
```

I've tried also without BitConverter:

```
        var b = new BitArray(new int[] { 0xfa2 });
```

But none of these attempt seem to work. These are the attempts that was suggested here: [Convert int to a bit array in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758196/convert-int-to-a-bit-array-in-net)

My output: 01000101111100000000000000000000.
The excpected output: 111110100010.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Seems about right, except for some leading zeroes

Comment: It has to do with the endienness of the architecture.  Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217980/c-sharp-little-endian-or-big-endian

Comment: do you expect 12 bits instead of 32? or are you talking about the order of the bits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looping from the wrong direction. Try this:

```
    var b = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(0xfa2));
    for (int i = b.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char c = b[i] ? '1' : '0';
        Console.Write(c);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a Little-Endian vs Big-Endian issue, so you need to take the endienness of the hw architecture into consideration.  Also based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you need to change the way you print the BitArray.

```
byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)0xfa2);

if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(buffer);

var b = new BitArray(buffer);

for (int i = 0; i < b.Count; i+=8)
{
    for (int j=i + 7; j >= i; j--)
    {
        char c = b[j] ? '1' : '0';
        Console.Write(c);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine();
```

---

Reference:

- From [BitArray Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation

> The first byte in the array represents bits 0 through 7, the second
>   byte represents bits 8 through 15, and so on. The Least Significant
>   Bit of each byte represents the lowest index value: " bytes [0] & 1"
>   represents bit 0, " bytes [0] & 2" represents bit 1, " bytes [0] & 4"
>   represents bit 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in documentation [BitArray Constructor (Int32[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3d1dwck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The number in the first values array element represents bits 0 through 31, the second number in the array represents bits 32 through 63, and so on. The Least Significant Bit of each integer represents the lowest index value: " values [0] & 1" represents bit 0, " values [0] & 2" represents bit 1, " values [0] & 4" represents bit 2, and so on.

When use this constructor there no need to check endianness, just reverse output order:

```
var b = new BitArray(new int[] { 0xfa2 });
// skip leading zeros, but leave least significant bit:
int count = b.Count;
while (count > 1 && !b[count-1])
    count--;
// output
for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    char c = b[i] ? '1' : '0';
    Console.Write(c);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```