# Is there a way to use AVX/AVX512 instrinsics in a SSE-compiled module?

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx512

Compilers: all of the three clang11 / gcc10 / msvc (vs2019).

What I want to write

```
my_math_func(raw_pointers_to_data)
{
    if (CpuSupportsAvx512()) {
        /* processing data via __m512  and _mm512_intrinsics */
    } else if(CpuSupportsAvx2()) {
        /* processing data via AVX2-specific */
    } else {
        /* processing data via SSE4 */
    }
}
```

The problem is that GCC (and AFAIK clang) refuse to compile when I set the `-msse4.2`.

If I set `-mavx512f` then the compiler can generate avx512 specific instructions *anywhere* in the binary, which is unacceptable for me.

The question is, is there a way to tell the compiler "please, let me use AVX+ intrinsics where I want, but don't generate avx+ instructions anywhere else" without using raw assembly or moving code to a separate dynamic library?

I'm ready to take responsibility (and future `ERROR: Illegal Instruction`) for checking that my avx512 blocks won't run on an incompatible CPU.

Comment: You'll need to write the AVX512 code in a separate function. And then you can use an attribute or pragma to tell gcc to compile this function for a different target, or more simply put the function in a different file that you compile with other options.

Comment: The simplest way is just let the compiler and linker handle this with the function multi-version feature using the `target` and `target_clones` attributes: [Building backward compatible binaries with newer CPU instructions support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61005492/995714), [Generate code for multiple SIMD architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44479069/995714)