# Converting Dword into Bit array in C#

Tags: c#, bit, dword

I am working in an app that connects to a Siemens PLC using LibnoDave library. I am getting a Dword value that I convert it into an INT value, but now I need to convert this INT value into a BIT array. For example, I get as a INT value the number 62000 that in binary is ‭1111001000110000‬. I need that value. How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert int to a bit array in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758196/convert-int-to-a-bit-array-in-net)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to represent `uint` in binary, try using `Convert` class:

```
  uint source = 62000;

  string result = Convert.ToString(source, 2);

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome

```
  1111001000110000
```

If you want `System.Collections.BitArray` instance:

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Linq; 

  ...

  uint source = 62000;

  BitArray array = new BitArray(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian 
    ? BitConverter.GetBytes(source)
    : BitConverter.GetBytes(source).Reverse().ToArray());

  // Test
  string result = string
    .Concat(array
       .OfType<bool>()
       .Reverse()
       .Select(item => item ? 1 : 0))
    .TrimStart('0');

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome

```
  1111001000110000
```

Comment: Is `Convert.ToString` always treat number as big endian? Side note: `TrimStart('0')` seems to be unnecesasry. If you for example use `uint source = 0` - result will be empty string, while expected result (I think) is string with 16 zeroes.

Comment: @Evk: Thank you! I agree with endians check; but since the `result` just demonstrates `array` contains correct data (for a single `62000` test) let me keep `TrimStart` as it is.

Comment: But that's because you use `uint`. Since OP says that 62000 is represented as 2 bytes - you have to use `ushort`. `INT` he uses in question can mean anything, because as I understand it's not C# int. And with `ushort` you can remove `TrimStart`. Your endianess check is also a bit strange, because you reverse once if `BitConverter` is not little endian, and then you reverse once again when working with BitArray. So you need to reverse if BitConverter is little endian and remove `Reverse()` when doing `Concat`.

Comment: If I understand the question right, it's about `DWORD` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx "**32-bit** unsigned integer", that's why I've put `uint` (`UInt32`)

Comment: Well he converts DWORD into some INT value, and that INT value he needs to convert to bit array (maybe INT is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230334.aspx in which case we are both wrong). Anyway, OP indeed can decide himself what he means.

Comment: `BitArray` starts from lower bit, e.g. `BitArray array = [true, false]` represents `2` but we want reversed `10` test outcome; just put `byte source = 2;` (in order to eliminate endians effect) and, please, see;

Answer (score 0):

The question is that in that DWORD I only need the second word. For exampel if I receive 11111111111111110000000000000000 , I only need the 1111111111111111 of this Dword.