# C# - Construct a signal Vector<T> from an integer bitmask

Tags: c#, vector, simd, intrinsics, bitmask

I have some integer value representing a bitmask, for example 154 = `0b10011010`, and I want to construct a corresponding signal [`Vector<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=net-5.0) instance `<0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1>` <sup>(note the least/most significant bit order is reversed)</sup>.

Is there any more performant way than this (beyond [unrolling the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70436545/2799848))?

```
int mask = 0b10011010;// 154
// -1 = (unsigned) 0xFFFFFFFF is the "all true" value
Vector<int> maskVector = new Vector<int>(
    Enumerable.Range(0, Vector<int>.Count)
        .Select(i => (mask & (1 << i)) > 0 ? -1 : 0)
        .ToArray());
// <0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1>
string maskVectorStr = string.Join("", maskVector);
```

<sup>(Note [the debugger is bugged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70416259/2799848) displaying `Vector<T>` values, showing only half of the components and the rest as zeros, hence my use of `string.Join`.)</sup>

Namely, **is there a way with only a single instruction?** It is the `Single Instruction, Multiple Data` (SIMD) datatype after all!

Furthermore, how I can do this when working with the generic `Vector<T>` version?

---

A signal vector, or integral mask vector, is used with the `ConditionalSelect` method to choose between values of two other masks:

```
//powers of two <1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128>
Vector<int> ifTrueVector = new Vector<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, Vector<int>.Count).Select(i => 1 << i).ToArray());
Vector<int> ifFalseVector = Vector<int>.Zero;// or some other vector
// <0, 2, 0, 8, 16, 0, 0, 128>
Vector<int> resultVector = Vector.ConditionalSelect(maskVector, ifTrueVector, ifFalseVector);
string resultStr = string.Join("", resultVector);
// our original mask value back
int sum = Vector.Dot(resultVector, Vector<int>.One);
```

[image]

---

The documentation of [`ConditionalSelect`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector.conditionalselect?view=net-5.0) explicitly says the mask vector has integral values for every overload, but spamming `Vector<T>.Zero[0]` and `Vector<T>.One[0]` to get them is surely improper? <sup>(And you can get the `T` version of -1 with `(-Vector<T>.One)[0]`)</sup>

<sub>P.S. would there also be a corresponding solution to populating with powers of 2?</sub>

Comment: How did you get from `0b10011010` to `<0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1>`?

Comment: Reverse the order. The least significant bit is the first vector component.

Comment: (Note that your `ConditionalSelect` could use be an `&`, I think? That means no need for `ifFalseVector`. [See the implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Vector.cs,38584787341a65da))

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your code.  The operation requires looping 16 times.

Comment: This is occurring in a performance-critical part of a rendering engine, which otherwise only performs two `ConditionalSelect` statements from the bitmask (and sometimes two subtractions), and intrinsics only take a couple CPU cycles.

Comment: @canton7 this is simplified for my question. I'm using two nontrivial vectors with `ConditionalSelect`.

Comment: Can you use `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86`? If so, there's x86 specific efficient solution

Comment: As @Alex said, if you can use x86 intrinsics, see [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675) for a list of strategies for different mask width / vec element sizes, with C++ intrinsics that you can port.

Comment: Just curious, why did you accept no answer?

Comment: I need to spend some quality time testing the provided answers first. They both look quite good.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do the complement of it with the vector operations offered by the `Vector` API, and equivalent variants could be made for any `T`, for example like this for `T = int`:

```
Vector<int> powersOfTwo;

Vector<int> MaskToElements(int mask)
{
    Vector<int> broadcasted = new Vector<int>(mask);
    Vector<int> singlebit = Vector.BitwiseAnd(broadcasted, powersOfTwo);
    return Vector.Equals(singlebit, powersOfTwo);
}
```

Where `powersOfTwo` is created like this:

```
int[] powersOfTwoArray = new int[Vector<int>.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < powersOfTwoArray.Length; i++)
{
    powersOfTwoArray[i] = 1 << i;
}
powersOfTwo = new Vector<int>(powersOfTwoArray);
```

It's not really generic, even though it would work for different types, largely because `powersOfTwo` must be precomputed otherwise this function won't make any sense: if there is a scalar loop in it anyway, what's the point.

---

If the mask is a constant, then with the System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86 API it can go directly into a [Blend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse41.blend?view=net-6.0), it doesn't need to be turned into a vector mask first, for example:

```
Vector128.AsInt32(Sse41.Blend(Vector128.AsSingle(a), Vector128.AsSingle(b), (byte)mask));
```

If the mask is not a constant, that API will still accept it, but it ends up calling a slow fallback. In that case, it's better to make a vector mask and use `BlendVariable`.

Comment: Other strategies for other element widths shown in: [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675).  A different strategy is required for small elements, when the bitmask is wider than an element.  e.g. 16 bits -> vector of 16x bytes.

Answer (score 3):

There might be a fancy vector-based way to generate your mask vector, but simply optimizing your current code can speed things up by over an order of magnitude.

Firstly, don't use Linq on hot paths. The number of intermediate object allocations, virtual method calls and delegate invocations going on there is simply unnecessary if you're looking for speed. You can rewrite this as a `for` loop with no loss of clarity.

Secondly, get rid of that array allocation. `Vector<T>` has constructors which take a `Span<T>`, and you can `stackalloc` one of those.

That gives you some code which looks a bit like this:

```
int mask = 0b10011010;

Span<int> values = stackalloc int[Vector<int>.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < Vector<int>.Count; i++)
{
    values[i] = (mask & (1 << i)) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
}

var maskVector = new Vector<int>(values);
```

Interestingly, manually unrolling that loop gives you another significant speed-up:

```
Span<int> values = stackalloc int[Vector<int>.Count];
values[0] = (mask & 0x1) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
values[1] = (mask & 0x2) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
values[2] = (mask & 0x4) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
values[3] = (mask & 0x8) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
values[4] = (mask & 0x10) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
values[5] = (mask & 0x20) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
values[6] = (mask & 0x40) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
values[7] = (mask & 0x80) > 0 ? -1 : 0;

var maskVector = new Vector<int>(values);
```

---

How does this perform? Let's use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org):

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class MyBenchmark
{
    [Benchmark, Arguments(0b10011010)]
    public Vector<int> Naive(int mask)
    {
        Vector<int> maskVector = new Vector<int>(
            Enumerable.Range(0, Vector<int>.Count)
                .Select(i => (mask & (1 << i)) > 0 ? -1 : 0)
                .ToArray());

        return maskVector;
    }

    [Benchmark, Arguments(0b10011010)]
    public Vector<int> Optimised(int mask)
    {
        Span<int> values = stackalloc int[Vector<int>.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < Vector<int>.Count; i++)
        {
            values[i] = (mask & (1 << i)) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
        }

        var output = new Vector<int>(values);
        return output;
    }

    [Benchmark, Arguments(0b10011010)]
    public Vector<int> Optimised2(int mask)
    {
        Span<int> values = stackalloc int[Vector<int>.Count];
        values[0] = (mask & 0x1) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
        values[1] = (mask & 0x2) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
        values[2] = (mask & 0x4) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
        values[3] = (mask & 0x8) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
        values[4] = (mask & 0x10) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
        values[5] = (mask & 0x20) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
        values[6] = (mask & 0x40) > 0 ? -1 : 0;
        values[7] = (mask & 0x80) > 0 ? -1 : 0;

        var output = new Vector<int>(values);
        return output;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<MyBenchmark>();
    }
}
```

This gives the results:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19044.1415 (21H2)
Intel Core i7-8565U CPU 1.80GHz (Whiskey Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.101
  [Host]     : .NET 5.0.0 (5.0.20.51904), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.1 (5.0.120.57516), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | mask | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Naive | 154 | 103.018 ns | 2.0509 ns | 4.0001 ns | 0.0554 | 232 B |
| Optimised | 154 | 13.405 ns | 0.3004 ns | 0.4497 ns | - | - |
| Optimised2 | 154 | 9.668 ns | 0.2827 ns | 0.8245 ns | - | - |

Comment: Dang I was hoping for some obvious, or special-purpose function to do it directly, but also dang good speedup!

Comment: @Elaskanator Turns out unrolling that loop gets you another decent speed-up

Comment: Is there any hope of generalizing this to the generic `Vector<T>` and not just `int`? And what if the value of `Vector<int>.Count` isn't 8 one day?

Comment: @Elaskanator Yeah, that's where the unrolled loop falls down. But then, if it decreases one day your code's already in trouble. I assume you're thinking of letting `T` be another integer type? Something like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/6zwjXW